# Lambda function to import json data from AWS API Gateway and insert into Mysql table

Tags: mysql, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a setup to receive a webhook with json data through AWS API Gateway and invoke the Lambda function. I need help with making the lambda function to insert the json parameter data as a new row into the mysql database table.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create json data type based column in mySql table if already not exist

CREATE TABLE `book` (
`id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
`tags` JSON DEFAULT NULL,
);

Then simply add insert query into code of lambda function for that JSON field.

Note: If your database is on RDS then you need to out your lambda function in VPC to communicate with RDS database and specify inbound rule in security group of RDS database for lambda function security group as source on port 3306